# aws ec2 describe-instance-status filter by tag not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

I am trying to get all ec2 instance that have schedules events and filter by a tag name. But the filter by tag throws an error. 
I am trying the below command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=*xyz*"
```

The above command throws:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeInstanceStatus operation: 
The filter 'tag:Name' is invalid
```

However when I run the same filer on describe-instances, it works fine:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=*xyz*"
```

The above command returns the ec2 instances as expected.

It happens on boto3 as well.
Please help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filters that are accepted by describe-instance-status are documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-status.html). As can be seen, filtering by tag is not an option. You will probably need to firstly get the list of instance-ids using describe-instances and filtering by tag, and then for each of these instance-ids, find the instance status.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the info. Could you please explain whats the meaning of dict-- part documented on boto 3 api. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instance_status

Comment: A dict is an abbreviation for dictionary, a Python data structure https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: @Bharathi, if this solved your problem please accept the answer.